# Is there any way to set a max value on an html text input?

Tags: html, button, input

I am making a program that requires the user to input a string into an HTML text input box but it has to be four characters. Is there any way to set a max value for the input? Also can you make it so it can only be numbers?     Here is what I mean:

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<h1>Please enter a four digit pin number:</h1>
<input type=text id=pin_number **maxvalue=4**>
/*Maybe you can do it with buttons*/
<table><tr><td><input type="button" value="1>"</td><td><input type="button" value="2>"</td>
<td><input type="button" value="3>"</td></tr><tr><td><input type="button" value="4>"</td><td><input type="button" value="5>"</td>
<td><input type="button" value="6>"</td></tr><tr><td><input type="button" value="7>"</td><td><input type="button" value="8>"</td>
<td><input type="button" value="9>"</td></tr></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/input.number.html

Answer (score 3):

```
<input type="number" max="9999" min="0" required value="0">
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Curry/LfuWk/2/).

Comment: That solves the Number problem but you can still type any number you want.

Comment: Not all browsers support it completely yet. To get better across-the-board coverage in all browsers you'll need Javascript.

Comment: [Check updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Curry/LfuWk/2/) and try to submit a PIN code of 12345 - it's stopped at submit time by the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, using the [HTML5 pattern attribute](http://blog.staffannoteberg.com/2012/03/01/html5-form-validation-with-regex/):

```
<input type='text' pattern='\d\d\d\d' />
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/66uL3/)

Again, I'm supposing you want exactly four digits.  ***And you can type anything you want in, but an error is thrown when you click submit***

Answer (score 0):

Use Javascript and regular expressions like this:

```
<html>
<head>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

function pinnotify() {
    var notify = document.getElementById('notify');
    var numberRegex = new RegExp("^[0-9]+$");
    var text = document.getElementById("pin");

    if(numberRegex.test(text.value)){
            notify.innerHTML = '<a style="font-size:1em;">Looks good!</a>';
    }else{
            notify.innerHTML = '<a style="font-size:1em;">Please numbers only.</a>';
    }

    if(text.value.length > 4){
            text.value = text.value.substring(0,4);
    }


}

</script>


</head>
<body>


<h1>Please enter a four digit pin number:</h1>

<form method="post" action="">
<input type="text" name="pin" id="pin" size="32" onkeyup="return pinnotify();"> <span id="notify"></span><br/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my way to filter digits and check max value in a text field.

It works in any browser

JS function:

```
function InputReplaceForInt(input, max) {
    if(max > 0 && input.value.length > max) {
        input.value = input.value.substr(0,max);
    }
    input.value = input.value.replace(/[^\d]/g, '');
}
```

Html code:

```
<input name="telephone"  type="text" onkeyup="InputReplaceForInt(this,11)"/>
```